# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Root.Stops> to

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to get the value of the `arrivalTime` from the JSON array `stops` but I am getting this error below

> - Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to 
>      Map
> - arrivalTime cannot be resolved or is not a field

How can I fix it?

I appreciate any help.

**Simple:**

```
[
    {
        "stops": [
                   {
                     "arrival_time": {
                                      "sat": [ "04:41", "05:41","06:09"],
                                      "mon-fri": ["04:24","05:10","05:40"],
                                      "sun": ["07:20","08:20","09:20"]
                                     },
                     "stop_name": "Ravensbusch "
                   }
                ],
        "route": "2",
        "direction": "Bornkamp"
    }
]
```

**Root class:**

```
public class Root {

    public List<Stops> stops = new ArrayList<Stops>();
    public String route;
    private String direction;


    public static class Stops {

        public Map<String, String[]> arrivalTime = new HashMap<>();
        public String stopsName;

    }
}
```

**Injection class:**

```
public class Injection {



        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            InputStream is = Injection.class.getResourceAsStream("/jsonfile.txt");

            List<Root> roots = mapper.readValue(is, TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
                    .constructCollectionType(List.class, Root.class));
            Root root = roots.get(0);

            System.out.println("route: " + root.route);
            //here is the error.
            Map<String, String[]> arrivalTimes = root.stops.arrivalTime;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry: arrivalTimes.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                for (String time: entry.getValue()) {
                    System.out.println(time);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: One suggestion, not related to correctness: instead of `TypeFactory.defaultInstance` use `mapper.getTypeFactory()`. Some modules add custom `TypeFactory` instances (Scala), so that is more maintainable.

Comment: Ok thanks I will take it in consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you were missing annotations for jackson (Especially due to the fact that arrival_time and StopsName are different in Json and in member name. This worked for me:

```

```
public class Stops {

    public Map<String, String[]> arrivalTime = new HashMap<>();
    public String stopsName;

    @JsonCreator
    public Stops(@JsonProperty("arrival_time") Map<String, String[]> arrivalTime,
                 @JsonProperty("stop_name") String stopsName) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
        this.stopsName = stopsName;
    }
}

public class Root {

    public List<Stops> stops = new ArrayList<Stops>();
    public String route;
    private String direction;

    @JsonCreator
    public Root(@JsonProperty("stops") List<Stops> stops,
                @JsonProperty("route") String route,
                @JsonProperty("direction") String direction) {
        this.stops = stops;
        this.route = route;
        this.direction = direction;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String is = "[{\"stops\":[{\"arrival_time\":{\"sat\":[\"04:41\",\"05:41\",\"06:09\"],\"mon-fri\":[\"04:24\",\"05:10\",\"05:40\"],\"sun\":[\"07:20\",\"08:20\",\"09:20\"]},\"stop_name\":\"Ravensbusch \"}],\"route\":\"2\",\"direction\":\"Bornkamp\"}]";
    List<Root> roots = mapper.readValue(is, TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
            .constructCollectionType(List.class, Root.class));
    // Rest of your code here
}
```

```

Comment: I have changed my code as your version but the problem is with the rest of the code `Map<String, String[]> arrivalTimes = root.stops.arrivalTime;` I am getting `- arrivalTime cannot be resolved or is 
  not a field
 - arrivalTime cannot be resolved or is 
  not a field`

Comment: stops is a list and I dont know if I can access `root.stops.arrivalTime;` arrivalTime like this?

Comment: You cannot, as it is a list - it has multiple stops each has it's own `arrivalTime` - If you want the first - you can change the line to be: `        Map<String, String[]> arrivalTimes = root.stops.iterator().next().arrivalTime;`. Otherwise you need to iterate over the list and get the stop object, and only then access the `arrivalTime`

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use the Json annotations. Follow below my findings.

```
public class Root {

    public List<Stops> stops = new ArrayList<Stops>();
    public String route;
    public String direction; //Fix: Make it public 

    public static class Stops {

        //Fix: Change attribute name to match input file arrival_time.
        public Map<String, String[]> arrival_time = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        //Fix: Change attribute name to match input file stop_name.
        public String stop_name;

    }
}

public class Injection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //InputStream is = Injection.class.getResourceAsStream("./jsonfile.txt");
        //List<Root> roots = mapper.readValue(is, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Root.class));

        //Fix: Read from file without input stream.
        List<Root> roots = mapper.readValue(new File("./jsonfile.txt"), TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Root.class));
        Root root = roots.get(0);

        System.out.println("route: " + root.route);

        //Fix: Read the first Item of the stops list or iterates it.
        Map<String, String[]> arrivalTimes = root.stops.get(0).arrival_time;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry: arrivalTimes.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            for (String time: entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println(time);
            }
        }
    }
}
```